# linq exception : This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get data which is kept on cache. But it throws an exception on "select new FilterSsrsLog" line. Exception: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities

```
List<ExecutionLog3> reportServerDB = UpdateCache();
        var reportLog = (from r in reportServerDB
                         orderby r.TimeStart descending
                         where ((model.reportName == null ? true : r.ItemPath.Contains(model.reportName)) &&
                          (model.reportFolder == null ? true : r.ItemPath.Contains(model.reportFolder)) &&
                          (r.TimeStart >= startDateTime) &&
                          (r.TimeStart <= endDateTime)
                         )
                   select new FilterSsrsLog
                   {
                       UserName = r.UserName,
                       ReportName = r.ItemPath,
                       ReportFolder = r.ItemPath,
                       Format = r.Format,
                       Parameters = r.Parameters,
                       TimeStart = r.TimeStart,
                       TimeEnd = r.TimeEnd,
                       TotalTime = EntityFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(r.TimeStart, r.TimeEnd)
                   });
```

If i remove "select new FilterSsrsLog" code block and write "select r" it works. But i need only that coloumns so what can i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is that the query is executed in memory, not in RDBMS. The `DiffMilliseconds` function is a marker that Entity Framework provider converts to RDBMS-specific SQL to send to your RDBMS. The function does not compute its result when applied to an `IQueryable<T>` in memory, throwing an exception instead.

If you want to run this query in memory, replace

```
TotalTime = EntityFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(r.TimeStart, r.TimeEnd)
```

with

```
TotalTime = (r.TimeEnd - r.TimeStart).TotalMilliseconds
```

Subtraction of two dates produces a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) value from which you can take its [`TotalMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx) property.

Comment: Wouldn't it be TotalMilliseconds?

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Ah, you're right, it should be `TotalMilliseconds`. Thanks!