# DbFunctions.DiffDays() results in: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Where `results1` is an `IQuerable<myObject>` that works fine until you try and filter by date:

```
results1 = results1.Where(l => DbFunctions.DiffDays(FromDate, l.LeadDate) >= 0);
```

And then I get this error:

> This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities

I've seen a few other threads here that get me close to an answer, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166183/linq-exception-this-function-can-only-be-invoked-from-linq-to-entities), but it's just different enough that I'm not sure how to reformulate this filter so that it doesn't try and do this in memory (which is why I *think* the error is happening?)

**EDIT:**

The query was too complex to get it working in Linq.  I thought this would be the same, but maybe not?

```
var query1 = @"
    SELECT 
        // columns that match the object 'myObject'
     FROM 
         // a whole bunch of joins and left joins
     ORDER BY
         ....";
 var results1 = Context.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<myObject>(query1).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: How do you create your `results1` object?

Comment: @DavidG see edit to OP.  And thank you!!

Comment: Try `Where(l =>(FromDate- l.LeadDate).Days>=0)`

Comment: @octavioccl: TimeSpan does not contain a definition for 'days'.  But, I'll keep pulling on that thread

Comment: I don't think you can tack on additional Linq to Entities to a raw sql query.

Comment: @juharr, looks like you are right?  I thought that .AsQueryable() would solve that.

Comment: Linq to Entities only turns Linq into SQL, it would have to parse your raw Sql to Linq and then tack on your additions and then translate back to SQL, which it just doesn't do for obvious reasons (your raw SQL might have unsupported bits that don't map).  So you'll have to do additional filtering in memory or update your raw SQL.

Comment: Try `Where(l => FromDate.Date > l.LeadDate.Date)` if you just want to know if the date portion of `FromDate` is before the date portion of `LeadDate` which is basically what your `DateDiff` should be doing.

Comment: What problem were you encountering while converting the query into linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `DateTime.Subtract` and `TimeSpan.Days`?

```
results1 = results1.Where(l => FromDate.Subtract(l.LeadDate).Days >= 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Not `TotalDays` since that will result in fractional values like 0.5 if the difference is 12 hours where as DateDiff in TSQL would possibly return 0 if the day portion is the same.

Comment: @juharr Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Because you are running a raw SQL query (i.e. using [`SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx)), the result of that is a materialised set of data. This means the query has already been passed to your data store and the data passed back as a [`DbRawSqlQuery<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbrawsqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx). This is not the same kind of queryable interface that you can build upon as you would normally extend an EF query.

You can either add to the raw SQL query or use a method from the .Net Framework or write your own.

Comment: "add to the raw SQL query"?

Comment: Yes, pass in `FromDate` as a parameter to the query and use it in the query.

Comment: ah ok I see what you mean