# Date difference : This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities .

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please hoe do I resolve this problem

**This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities**

This is my code

```
        public long TodayNotifications()
    {
        long notifications = _notificationsService.GetNotifications().Where(x => DbFunctions.DiffDays(x.NOTIFICATION_DATE, DateTime.Now) == 0).Count();

        return notifications;
    }
```

Comment: You have to make sure your `GetNotifications()` returns `IQueryable<T>`. Otherwise, change your `Where()` criteria to perform the days-diff calculation using standard `DateTime` methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DbFunctions.DiffDays() results in: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934531/dbfunctions-diffdays-results-in-this-function-can-only-be-invoked-from-linq-t)

Comment: please how do I make sure your GetNotifications() returns IQueryable<T>

Comment: if it returns a collection other than `IQueryable`, then you can try this `_notificationsService.GetNotifications().Count(x => x.NOTIFICATION_DATE.Date == DateTime.Today)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `DbFunctions` if you are not using Linq to Entities. It seems you are calling a web service that returns `IEnumerable` or something which implements `IEnumerable`. You can just check if the date component of the date is equal like this:

```
long notifications = _notificationsService.GetNotifications()
    .Where(x => x.NOTIFICATION_DATE.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).Count();
```

See [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) for more in case you want to use the `Subtract` method which does a date diff. Here is an example:

```
var date1 = new DateTime();
var date2 = date1.AddDays(1);
var days = date2.Subtract(date1).TotalDays;
```

Comment: Thanks. But why am I having another error **A cyclic reference was detected while serializing an object** in the code '    public JsonResult SelectStates(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<BPP.CCSP.Admin.Web.BPPCCSPAdminStatesService.STATES> states = _statesService.GetStates().Where(stat => stat.COUNTRY_ID == id);
        return Json(states);
    }'

Comment: @gbenga i am not sure. Please ask another question since this is a whole new issue and i am sure someone will help you. Also, search for *cyclic reference during serialization* and it may point you in the right direction.